# WebKit CSS Transforms: Scaling doesn't work on Retina Mac if the scale factor is greater than 1 for certain HTML elements

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, webkit, retina-display

Sample Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pmLs1cxv/5/

HTML:

```
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" class="two" />
    <input type="radio" class="two" />
    <button type="submit" class="two"></button>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="radio" />
    <button type="submit"></button>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.two {
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

I have a radio button and a checkbox that I apply transform: scale(2) to. On my Thunderbolt (not retina) display, they scale properly to 2x, like so:
[image: Thunderbolt]

But then I drag the same window over to my Retina MacBook's display, and they suddenly turn back to original size, like so:
[image: Retina]

I did not do anything to the window or inside the window, I just dragged the window between the two displays. Whenever the window is on the Thunderbolt Display, the controls pop back into 2x mode, and when the window is on the Retina MacBook's display, they pop back to original size. How do I ensure they scale on retina displays? (Using transform: scale(4) doesn't do anything; it isn't a matter of retina displays requiring 2x the scale factor.)

Note: I tested in Chrome 44 and Safari 8.0.7 and the behavior occurs in both, thus my titling the question WebKit. Interestingly, using zoom: 200% instead of transform: scale(2) causes Chrome to render the boxes in a different style that bypasses this issue, but that doesn't work in Safari, where it exhibits the same behavior described above. I have tested this on multiple Retina MacBook Pros and they all exhibit this behavior, so it is not an issue local to my machine.

**EDIT:** I modified the fiddle to include a `<button>` element as well, and same thing occurs, so this is not limited to radios and checkbox inputs.

**EDIT 2:** I tested `<img>` elements and they scale properly. As a result I don't think this is an issue for all elements, just specific ones, and I have found that it impacts radio buttons, checkboxes, and buttons so far.

Comment: Does this happen in other browsers like Firefox or Internet Explorer? (Just trying to narrow down where the problem might be...)

Comment: No. IE and FF render them as expected. I'm pretty certain this is WebKit.

Comment: I don't have a retina display, so I'm not confident enough to answer, but have you experimented with the -webkit-appearance property? https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/

Comment: I have tried them actually, and they did not affect the rendering. By the way, props for not flooding this question with irrelevant answers.

Comment: So just to clarify, scale(2) and scale(4) both result in no change on a Retina screen? Scale appears to be ignored?

Comment: That is correct. Any factor above 1 is ignored. At this point I can pretty much conclude this requires a WebKit fix, but I'm just holding out hope that there's a way to work around this without that since their Bugzilla is filled with untouched bug reports so their attention on this is unlikely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86919/discussion-between-ben-visness-and-display-name).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using CSS 3D transforms instead. For example, instead of `transform: scale(2)` you can use `transform: scale3d(2,2,1)`.

This works because using 3D transforms forces Webkit browsers to create a new GPU layer for that element instead of transforming it using other methods. From [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/) by Paul Lewis and Paul Irish of the Chrome team:

> In Blink and WebKit browsers a new layer is created for any element which has a CSS transition or animation on opacity, but many developers use translateZ(0) or translate3d(0,0,0) to manually force layer creation.

[This article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/layers/#toc-layercreation) by Tom Wiltzius of the Chrome Team has more criteria for what creates a layer and what does not. (Warning: That article was written in 2013 and may not be fully accurate now.)

This sounds like a legitimate WebKit bug, though. I would recommend reporting it to either the WebKit or Chrome teams.

Comment: This might be related: [forcing hardware acceleration in WebKit](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css)

Comment: Note: need the -webkit vendor prefix for Safari as of 8.0.7 because apparently it doesn't support scale3d natively.

Answer (score 0):

You should try adjusting the resolution on the monitor that you're having the problem on with the scaling.
Have you tried turning off dual display, and just use the monitor that have the scaling problem by itself to see if it still happens?

*I dont see a problem with the code though*

I just viewed your codes on my mac book pro, seems to be normal.

If none of that helps, you should try using decimals on the scale instead of whole     numbers.

Comment: None of this helps. Updated [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pmLs1cxv/3/) to use 2.0 for scale factor and went to it on a Retina MBP with no external monitors attached, still no scale. Having a customer adjust their resolution is not a solution in itself, and in this context, it doesn't fix the issue either. Are you using a regular MBP or Retina MBP?

Comment: Retina. Why dont you just use padding to space out the button from touching the other ones. Im kind of confused; is that the problem that you're trying to fix?

Comment: Adding padding to space out the controls doesn't actually make them bigger. This is for web accessibility reasons. (I verified the issue on multiple Retina MBPs so it isn't local to my machine.)

Comment: Before others comment on styling a same-level `<label>` to create custom controls and hiding the actual `<input>` to achieve accessibility - I cannot modify the markup in my specific case, and CSS scale not working in WebKit on a specific screen type is a valid issue in itself.

Comment: Here http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Hfw72/1/  ... 
You can try using the method from that example. Its actually not that easy to style the radio and check buttons using CSS because most of the times, it doesn't even respond to the height and width changes. So the best thing you can do is probably make a custom one using a label and input.

Comment: I think I just said in the above comment that I have no control over the markup. And actually, if CSS scaling works like it's supposed to, I can easily make the radio buttons and checkboxes respond to height and width changes.

Comment: Your only other option is to use zoom on the CSS instead. && I didnt see your previous comment. Scaling does work, but for that part of the HTML, alot of people have problems with the height and the width trying to make them bigger / smaller.

Comment: See the original question itself (near the end, in the Note: section) for my comments on zoom: circumvents the issue on Chrome because it somehow forces Chrome to render the controls differently, but does nothing on Safari.

Comment: Well, you're saying that you don't have access to the actual HTML codes, so im not really sure what else you can do at this point. They have techniques to do it using Javascript, but its useless if you dont have accessibility to the HTML.

Comment: Accessibility for radio buttons is my high level problem, which isn't what this question is asking. I isolated the cause to be WebKit's faulty rendering of CSS scale transforms on Retina screens. This question is regarding how to work around that WebKit bug. Everything not relating to the original question's issue is a tangent.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
-webkit-transform: scale(2);
-moz-transform: scale(2);
-o-transform: scale(2);
transform: scale(2);
```

Comment: Irrelevant. Both browsers I mentioned fully support transforms.